# How come my calculator loop fails after input becomes certain length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, math, calculator

My code is

```js
let firstInput = function(stringy) {

  let array = [...stringy]
  let regex = /[0-9]/;
  let reop = /[*/+-]/;
  let holder = [];
  //console.log(array)
  
  let filter = array.filter(function(x) {
    if (regex.test(x) === true || reop.test(x) === true) {
      return true
    } else null
  })
  
  filter.forEach(function(x) {
    if (regex.test(x) === true) {
      holder.push(parseFloat(x));
    } else {
      holder.push(x)
    }
  })
  
  return holder;
}

let arry = firstInput('8*all[]/3++++++++zzzy^^2-1');
console.log(arry)

let merged = arry.join('').split(/(\d+)/).filter(Boolean).map(x => +x || x);
console.log(merged)

merged.forEach(function(x) {
  if (typeof x === 'string') {
    if (x.length > 1) {
      console.log(x)
      console.log(merged.indexOf(x))
      let index = merged.indexOf(x)
      let replace = x.substring(0, 1)
      merged.splice(index, 1)
      merged.splice(index, 0, replace)
    }
  }
})

console.log(merged)
let arr = merged;

let calc = function() {

  if (arr.length > 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] === '*') {
        let multiply = arr[i - 1] * arr[i + 1]
        arr.splice(i - 1, 3)
        arr.splice(i - 1, 0, multiply)
      } else if (arr[i] === '/') {
        let div = arr[i - 1] / arr[i + 1]
        arr.splice(i - 1, 3)
        arr.splice(i - 1, 0, div)
      }
    }
  }
  
  if (arr.length > 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] !== '*' || arr[i] !== '/') {
        if (arr[i] === '+') {
          let add = arr[i - 1] + arr[i + 1]
          arr.splice(i - 1, 3)
          arr.splice(i - 1, 0, add)
        } else if (arr[i] === '-') {
          let minus = arr[i - 1] - arr[i + 1]
          arr.splice(i - 1, 3)
          arr.splice(i - 1, 0, minus)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  return arr
}

calc(merged)
console.log(calc())
```

Currently what goes into the calc function is this array `[8 ,"*" ,3 ,"+" ,2 ,"-" ,1]`  and I am returned 25. This is correct. When I add anything else such as `[8 ,"*", 3, "+", 2,"-", 1, '+', 1]`  I still get a single number as a return, but it is incorrect. Any insight as to why this is?

Also I'm being forced to raise my text to code ratio so everything prior to the calculator function is desired to take a random input string and calculate it if possible. Ie a number operator number.

Comment: lets say `arr = [3 + 2 - 1]`
If I am right, In `calc()`,Where `i = 1`  What you did is `add3+2 = arr[i - 1] + [i + 1] = 5 ` then you remove fitst 3 char so and add `add3+2` where u remove it. so now `arr = [5 - 1]`,this is a big problem.bsc where now `i = 2` as `arr[2] = 1` So you miss minus operator !

Comment: Oh I see. That is a pain. How would I get `i` to reset every time it makes this calculation?

Comment: `console.log(eval(['1','+','2','*','3'].join("")))  // 7`

Comment: Did I just Save Your Life?

Comment: hahaha maybeee. I heard eval has security issues though. Is there an alternative? (this string should be able to vary infinitely in length and basic operators. I was trying to avoid using eval :P also this is just a personal project c: fortunately

Comment: `eval()` is not that harmful as sound.You have to make sure that client should not access `eval()` bcs client could inject Code through `eval()` .In this uses client can't access evel()  operation...If  you don't want to use this shorthand for fun! In your code use recursive function.